# Overriding the currently selected menu item

Tags: pages, menus

I have a WP 3.x site that I'm using mainly as a CMS. The menu links to the various WordPress pages.

One of the pages, "News", is the "posts" page.

However, when clicking on one of the posts on the News page, the "News" item in the menu loses highlighting because the post isn't treated as a child of "news".

Is there an easy way to override the currently highlighted item in the menu? Ideally by forcing a page ID upon it.

Comment: Are you using `wp_list_pages` or `wp_nav_menu` to output the menu?

Comment: if its an internal interface and you dont mind hard coding it why not use CSS?? doesent that menu item have a "current" or similer class when selected?

Comment: @Sagive I'm using WP's built-in menu. The menu doesn't have a "current" class because WP doesn't recognize posts as children of the "posts" page. That's the issue - I'm using the "current" class everywhere else and I want to be able to use it in posts as well

Comment: i see... then maybe (just fishing here) if your using wp menus you could point to a category and not a post page.. that way it should work.. is there a link i can watch it? is it online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I assume you're using `wp_nav_menu()`, there should be a class `current_page_parent` which is applied to your posts' page menu item when viewing a single post.

You can use this class to style the 'active' state, much like you're probably doing with `current_page_item` at the moment.

If (for whatever reason) you must have `current_page_item` added too, you can filter the `nav_menu_css_class`:

```
/**
 * Add the class 'current_page_item' to 'page for posts' menu item if we're
 * viewing a single post.
 * 
 * @param array $class
 * @param object $item The current menu item.
 * @return array
 */
function add_current_class_to_posts_page( $classes, $item )
{
    static $posts_page;

    if ( ! is_single() )
        return $classes;

    if ( ! isset( $posts_page ) )
        $posts_page = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ); // cache as we may be calling this a lot!

    if ( $item->object == 'page' && $item->object_id == $posts_page )
        $classes[] = 'current_page_item'; // this is the posts page!

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_current_class_to_posts_page', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Re your edit, ahh, that looks interesting, I think I can work with that: Posts are not being treated as children of the posts page so neither `current_page_parent` nor `current_page_childrn` turn up, but I should be able to hack it using your code sample. I will try out and get back to you.

Comment: WordPress adds classes in a context-aware fashion. If you're viewing a post, it will add the class `current_page_parent` if the item is the  'posts page' - check out your source if you don't believe me!

Comment: Oh maaan, shame on me! I didn't check properly, it indeed is the way you say. I don't understand how I could overlook that. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: Makes me wonder why `$item->current` or `$item->current_parent` isn't `true`. Anyway: Elegant solution, ideal muplugin. +1